# Have a class have access to a parameter from another class

Tags: python, oop

I have two classes, `classA` and `classB`. `classA` has an attribute named `image` that contains data that is changing all the time. I want to be able to have an instance of `classB` that when I call a method on this instance, it can access `self.image` from `classA`. Unfortunately my attempts are failing.

Example code:

```
classA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = None #initialise
        analysis = classB(self)

    def doingstuff(self):
        self.image = somethingchanginghere()
        measurement = analysis.find_something_cool()
        print measurement

classB:
   def __init__(self, master):
       self.image = master.image #get a reference to the data from other class

   def do_something_cool(self):
       return type(self.image) #find something about the data at the point when method is called

main = classA()
main.doingstuff()
```

I get an error that says the data is still `None`, i.e. it's still in the state when it was initialised and the reference to `classA` from `classB` hasn't updated when self.image in classA changed. What have I done wrong?

Why does the working example give `NoneType`? I'm expecting a random number.

Comment: Your `print` statements suggest Python 2.x, but you don't inherit from `object` so your classes are "old-style", which is bad practice. Also, without `class` this is syntactically invalid as posted. Is `numpy` actually relevant here? Could you cut down further to a [mcve]?

Comment: Simply do `self.master = master` and use `self.master.image`. That will keep updating as the object updates.

Comment: Also start with the class B first, this is confusing ! in the __init__ of class A you are __init__ class B, are you trying to build a factory pattern ?

Comment: I was using numpy to make the working example testable by other people. Looks like it's been edited out anyway. I don't understand what you mean by 'old style' classes

Comment: @deceze perfect! I've got it working exactly how I want it now. Why wasn't it working the other way?

Comment: @SamuelBancroft 1. well you edited it out, as far as the edit history says. 2. http://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/3001761

Comment: Because you're assigning a *value*, not a variable/attribute. If you assign `None` to `self.image`, then it'll stay that way.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the link - I'l have a good read. deceze That makes much more sense thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. `analysis` is a variable local to the `classA.__init__` and `classA.doingstuff` functions. If you wish to re-use it in other functions, you should define it as an attribute: `self.analysis = classB(self)`.
2. Python [doesn't pass variables by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference). When you do `analysis = classB(self)`, you create an object of `classB`, passing the object `self` as an argument. It is *not* a reference to the object, so `classB.image` is set and/or changed only once, in `classB.__init__`. If you wish to keep it updated, you should either do:

   ```
   classB:
       def __init__(self, master):
           self.master = master
   ```

   and then use `master.image` to get the image, or implement a `classB` method e.g.

   ```
   def update(self, image): 
       self.image = image
   ```

   and call it every time `image` changes.